# How to remove duplicate string from each row in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column that contains a bunch of 4 digit numbers separated by commas. Some contain duplicate sets of 4 digit numbers. For example, 1 row looks like this:

```
1400, 1400, 1400, 1455, 1455, 1455, 1670, 1670, 1670
```

I am trying to change that to this:

```
1400, 1455, 1670
```

I want to apply that to all rows within a column. I was able to get this from another question here.

```
df['ID'] = df['ID'].apply(lambda x: list(set(x)))
```

However, this is just filtering it down to unique single digits, like this:

```
1,4,0,5,6,7
```

How do I adjust the code to make this work?

Comment: I'd guess the content of your column is of type string. Then it creates the set based on the chars in it (but that wouldn't explain it filters to unique single digits, it should also show ',' and ' ')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep order of 'ID', you can use `np.unique` after extracting numbers from string:

```
df['ID'] = df['ID'].str.findall('\d{4}').map(np.unique).str.join(', ')
print(df)

# Output
0    1400, 1455, 1670
Name: ID, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html). But before that, make sure to [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) :

```
df["ID"] = df["ID"].str.split("\s*,\s*").map(set).str.join(", ")
```

You can modify you code by making an `str.split` right before you call `apply` :

```
df["ID"] = df["ID"].str.split("\s*,\s*").apply(lambda x : ", ".join(set(x)))
```

NB : Both approaches does not garantee/keep the order of numbers. So if the order is important, @*Corralien's* [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75324804/16120011) is what you're looking for.

​
Output :

```
print(df)
                 ID
0  1455, 1400, 1670
```

Comment: I really like `"\s*,\s*"` :-)

Comment: Highly inspired by Corralien ;)